# Runtime error while trying to record audio

Tags: android, audio-recording

I am going to create a simple voice recorder app using [this tutorial](https://medium.com/@ssaurel/create-an-audio-recorder-for-android-94dc7874f3d). When I run the app I get the following error:

> ```
>  java.lang.RuntimeException: setAudioSource failed.
>  .
>  .
>  .
>  Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: setAudioSource failed.
>     at android.media.MediaRecorder._setAudioSource(Native Method)
>     at android.media.MediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.java:715)
>     at com.willarium.escort.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:29)
> ```

this is line 29 of MainActivity:

```
myAudioRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
```

I have set the permissions in manifest like this:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"/>
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Are you using run time permissions?

Comment: Thank you. I don't know how to use it. Do I need to postpone the entire codes after checking run time permissions? @AnasMehar

Comment: Yes after Permission granted you can run your code.